# Wordpress: orderby LIKE instead of SORT

Tags: php, wordpress

There is list of people stored in Wordpress, each with teams associated to them.

We're searching for all members of the team, and would like to order them so that the **first person's `team_position` contains the words "team leader"**. Hopefully this is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated!

We also realise there could be two separate queries, one for the team leader and one excluding them from the rest of the team. However, we are trying to run this in a singular query if possible!

**Data Example**

```
people : [
  { name : "Steve Jobs"
  , team_position : "Teaching Team Leader"
  , team_associations : [1, 17, 21]
  }
  { name : "George Clooney"
  , team_position : "Teacher"
  , team_associations : [1, 17, 21]
  }
```

**Current PHP**

```
$args = array (
  'post_type'    => 'people',
  'meta_query'   => array(
    'key'     => 'team_association',
    'value'   => $teamId,
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
  ),
  'meta_key'     => 'team_position',
  'order'        => 'ASC' // Custom filter for "team leader" first required here
);

$team_query = new WP_Query( $args );


// The Loop
if ( $team_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
  <section class="team">
  <?
  while ( $team_query->have_posts() ) {
  $team_query->the_post();
  ?>

    <article class="team-member">
      <div class="team-member__name"><?=get_field('name');?>
      <div class="team-member__position"><?=get_field('team_position');?>
    </article>

  <?php } ?>
  </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does your current loop look like?

Comment: @rnevius extracts all team members from the correct team successfully, but orders alphabetically on the `team_position` field

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant loop...it'll be easier to show you how to modify it than for us to write a completely new loop.

Comment: @rnevius Have added an example loop into the question.